# Loading Texture in Unity always throws NullReferenceExpection

Tags: c#, null, unity-game-engine, textures, nullreferenceexception

I'm working in Unity 4.3.3f1 and I'm trying to load a Texture at runtime but I keep getting `NullReferenceExpection`.  I have my `.png` located in Asset/Resources as specified by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820890/loading-a-png-as-a-texture-at-runtime-in-unity3d).

My actual code is

```
  Texture tex = Resources.Load("lava_pic", typeof(Texture)) as Texture;
  Rect pos = new Rect(transform.position.x - 50, 
        transform.position.y - 50, 100, 100);

  GUI.DrawTexture(pos, tex);
```

I've also tried with the `.png` extension

The Error is

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.GUI.DrawTexture (Rect position, UnityEngine.Texture image, ScaleMode  
  scaleMode, Boolean alphaBlend, Single imageAspect) (at     
C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/EditorGenerated/GUI.cs:208)
UnityEngine.GUI.DrawTexture (Rect position, UnityEngine.Texture image) (at 
 C:/BuildAgent/work/d3d49558e4d408f4/artifacts/EditorGenerated/GUI.cs:204)
LavaScript.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/LavaScript.cs:35)'
```

If I put in a `Debug.Log(tex);` it also prints out `null` so that is where the problem is.

I really don't know why this is occurring. It's in a Resources folder since [that's where it needs to be](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html) and I'm fairly certain it can be a `.png` file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the file extension so it's just `lava_pic`.

Relevant info from the `Resources` [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html):

> ...extensions must be omitted

### Update

Working example from my machine.  It's possible if your original code is located outside of `OnGUI` that the null object is GUI and not the texture.

My texture is located at `Assets/Resources/galaxy_example.png`

```
public class DrawTexture : MonoBehaviour {
Texture tex;
Rect pos;
void Start () {
    tex = Resources.Load("galaxy_example", typeof(Texture)) as Texture;
    pos = new Rect(transform.position.x - 50, 
                   transform.position.y - 50, 100, 100);
}
void OnGUI(){
    Debug.Log (tex);
    GUI.DrawTexture(pos, tex);
}
}
```

Comment: Tried, same result :/

Comment: @Daniel Where are you calling this code from?  See my update in case you are testing you code outside of `OnGUI`

Comment: Behavior script for a prefab, FixedUpdate(). The script is inheriting from Monobehavior

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load a image inside the Asset/Resource folder use: `Resoure.Load("image",typeof(texture))` as texture.

If you want to load a image from other folder load full path:
`Texture2D Txt= Resources.LoadAssetAtPath<Texture2D> ("Assets/Sprites/Scene1.png");`