# Loading a table of texture from unity folder scripting while running on android device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, texture2d

i can load images from external urls and save them into my unity project folder when i run it on my pc (unity player scene) it works perfectly i can load the images located in my project into a table of textures and display it but it's not working while running on android device .it won't load images into texture

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"Assets\Photos\");
    int nbImage;

    nbImage = info.GetFiles("*.jpg").Length;
    Debug.Log(nbImage);
    Textures = new Texture2D[nbImage];
    for (int i = 0; i < nbImage; i++)
    {
        string e = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + i + ".jpg";
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(e);
        load_s01_texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        load_s01_texture.LoadImage(bytes);
        Textures[i] = load_s01_texture as Texture2D;


    }
```

this how it looks on my pc [image: works fine]
and this how it looks on my phone [image: not working]

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? If not, you can do it by enabling USB Debugging on your phone (in developer settings) and using ADB (one common command is `adb logcat -s Unity`).

Comment: yes i tried debugging it on android studio and i think it a problem on paths .he can't locate the paths of my images that i saved on my project

Answer (score 1):

The directory "Assets\Photos" exists when you are running the project in the Editor, but it doesn't exist on the Android phone.

If you want to load images or other resources at run time, you have to use the [resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) folder.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820890/loading-a-png-image-as-a-texture-at-runtime-in-unity3d) a useful example of how to use it

Comment: I'd add you can also use [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) on Android.

Comment: it's the same it won't display the images on my phone but it works proprely on my pc . I m using "Textures = Resources.LoadAll("Textures", typeof(Texture2D));" to get the images

Comment: I hadn't seen your response before. You are passing "Textures" to the LoadAll method, but in your question you mention the folder is named "Photos", so I assume the error was there